# How do I change hotkeys?

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I am trying to change the hotkeys for Age of Empires II: HD (version > 5.0), but I can't get it to work.

I download [this mapping file](https://aokhotkeys.appspot.com/presets/get/688003) (`.hki`, selecting HD5.0+ at the top left side) and I copy it into my game folder: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\common\Age2HD\profiles\`. However, this folder already has three profiles (player1.hky, player2.hki, player3.hki). I tried saving it as player4.hki as well as overwriting player3.hki, and using player0.hki but in none of these cases the actual new mapping was used - but it did seem to change slightly.

The thing is that I am trying to install an AZERTY layout, and still <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>W</kbd> (among others) are switched, even after installing these new files.

Can anyone provide a guide on how to correctly install these files, even when player*.hki files already exist? Which digit should be appended to the file name? A new one, 0, the latest one, and so on.

When I try to change the hotkeys in-game, I can't complete the process because of duplicate keys. Even though there are clearly duplicates in a single list (e.g. <kbd>Q</kbd> for house and barracks):

[image: default]

When I try to change both of those to <kbd>A</kbd>, I get a message that one of those was cancelled. So I am not able to put in duplicates.

[image: cancelled key]

Comment: Is your Windows keyboard set to AZERTY or QWERTY? and if you try to enter something into a input field in the game, what keyboard does that use?

Comment: @Nzall It's set to AZERTY and I can type in chat just like I normally would, in AZERTY.

Comment: Can't you just set hotkeys from the game client?

Comment: @BenCraig Yes and no. Even though the defaults contain some duplicates (e.g. q for house and barracks), whenever you try to add duplicates yourself (e.g. a for house and barracks) you get an error that you cannot use duplicate keys...

Comment: @BramVanroy House and Barracks are from different menus, so that would make sense to me. Similar to how archery range and mill are both W. I cant check right now, but I feel like it wont let you put stuff from the same menu as duplicates, but as long as theyre not from the same menu it should be fine.

Comment: @BenCraig I know they are, however in-game they are all under 'Villager Build'. (If you launch a game and then go to options > Hotkeys.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a really good tool for this [online](https://aokhotkeys.appspot.com/).

Essentially, AoE reads the hotkeys/bindings from the root installation directory and will set the keyboard to whatever that file reads. This site allows you to *easily* edit them in a nice-ish UI. Download it, replace and boot - should all work :)